# Glide выборочно загружает изображения по URL

Tags: android, url, download, glide

Пишу приложение в котором много картинок. Что бы уменьшить вес приложения я эти картинки загружаю с интернета в кеш приложения. Не которые картинки не загружаются вовсе. Но по URL которое я задаю на компьютере они загружаются.
На компьютере не стоит VPN. Это связано с политической ситуацией в моей стране. Некоторые иностранные ресурсы блокируются властями.

Но вот в чем состоит вопрос если они грузятся на компьютере без всяких дополнительных требований и программ нельзя ли улучшить мой код что бы они грузились в моём приложении?

Вот код отвечающий за загрузку приложения по URL

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.book)
                .error(R.drawable.book)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .priority(Priority.HIGH);
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap().apply(options)
                .load(itemModel.getUrl())
                .into(holder.itemImage);
```

Comment: Есть ли какие-то ошибки в логах? И вообще ошибки во время исполнения? Т.е. картинка для ошибки отображается вместо ожидаемой картинки? Попробуйте добавить слушатель для Glide и вывести в логи что-то из onError колбэка.

Comment: В стеке ничего нет. Поставлю логи но скорее всего будет ошибка типа долгое ожидание или время ожидания ответа закончилось

Comment: Ну, тогда, видимо, без проксирования никак не обойтись. Наверное у вас и браузер проксирует как-то. Попробуйте в нём всё поотключать или сменить его на что-то типа ie-8 - если дело в блокировках, то и в браузере картинки работать не будут. Если дело в этом - настраивайте прокси. Для этого надо или сторонними решениеями пользоваться или свой сервер поднимать. В любом из этих двух случаев вам придётся параметры прокси-сервера прописать в конфиг подключения Glide к сети.

Comment: Есть какой-то пример прописки прокси в Glide?

Comment: Сходу только такое нашёл: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597523/3212712. Там, кажется, не полный ответ и надо дополнительно выяснять как для OkHttp прокси прописать.